# Spring MVC - Configure StringHttpMessageConverter for an @RequestMapping method which return string that interpreted as the logical view name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, web

I'm trying make an `@RequestMapping` method which return a string(which is a path to a JSP file)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        logger.info("home");
        return "blog/home";
    }
```

it worked well until when I defined `mvc:annotation-driven` (i need to set it for being able to use `@ControllerAdvice`) in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file. So that's a my dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <import resource="controllers.xml" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/*;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

</beans>
```

The return of the`home()`method interpreted as HTTP body.
I'm getting this issue in my log

```
Written [redirect:/blog/home] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@61f77969]
```

I don't know what i'm missing that this path "blog/home" does not interpret as view reference

Comment: Why you are using <mvc:message-converters> inside <mvc:annotation-driven> tag?

Comment: In order to define a HTTP Message Converter. it explained in this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration)

Comment: I think it's not needed in your case.

Comment: I tried with ``<mvc:annotation-driven/>`` but even it didn't work ("block/home" didn't interpret as view reference)

Comment: How have you annotated your class... With `@Controller` or `@RestController`? Also the logging doesn't match what you write in your controller, so is this the actual code or have you left things out?

Comment: I annotated my class with ``@Controller``. I turn on the log of ``org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc`` project on TRACE level in my log file (``<logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc" level="TRACE" />``). So the logging shown above is result of that